# OnCompletionListener in videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview, ontouchlistener

I am using following code:

```
 videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                 //finish();
                }
            });
            videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
                        videoView.pause();
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

I have one problem: When onCompletion is fired, the app is closed atm. I would like it to only close when I touch the videoView again, however after onCompletion is fired, onTouch won't fire again.

What can I do to enable onTouch again after onCompletion is fired?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a flag for the `onCompletion`.

```
boolean mVideoCompleted = false;

videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mVideoCompleted = true;
    }
});

videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mVideoCompleted) {
            finish();
        }
        if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
            videoView.pause();
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that onTouch is not being called after onCompletion was called; I'm not entirely sure what that flag would accomplish?

Comment: `onTouch` was not called because you finished the activity so the activity that contains the video view is no longer there and you set the `onTouch` to the video view and that does not exists anymore.

Comment: I meant it doesn't get called if I don't call finish :)

Comment: Hmm from what i understand now it seams to me that you are setting the on completion listener in one activity and the touch in another. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I am setting the listeners in the same activity :)